# simple loop in rendered template django cms plugin

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-cms

I want to loop data taken from database in rendered template. Using cms plugin.
I dont have problem looping data in html template. But if i use CMSPlugin to insert new app in placeholder, nothing shows.

If i run url localhost:port/test.html.I got input what i want. But rendered template doesnt loop data.

```
{% for post in posts %}
   {{ post.firstoption }}
{% endfor %}
```

if I use code below, nothing shows in my rendered template. Values are passed in rendered template. Because, if i try {{instance.firstoption}} i get value shown in template. Problem is i cant loop data with tag instance.

```
{% for post in instance.posts %}
  {{ post.firstoption }}
{% endfor %}
```

I also tried `{% for post in instance.posts_set.all %}`
and `{% for post in instance.posts.all %}`

cms_plugins.py

```
class pricing(CMSPluginBase):
    model = mymodel
    name = _("myplugin")
    render_template = "template.html"
    cache = False

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context.update({'instance': instance})
        return context
```

models.py

```
class mymodel(CMSPlugin):
    firstoption = models.CharField(max_length=200)


        def __str__(self):
    return self.firstoption
```

Comment: Without any description of the `instance` model, the view, or anything else related, its hard to say what the issue would be. Please try to make a [mcve]

Comment: I can paste you my view and cms plugins. But fact is that {{instance.something}} works. All i want to know is how to make for loop with instance. I edited and pasted more code in my post

Comment: Add your view for starters and model

Comment: You need to show your model.

Comment: Show the code of model "**mymodel**" as defined in your code.

Comment: Updated answer as @PrakharTrivedi mentioned it should be `{{ post.firstoption }}`

Comment: You need to erase those % also. Write it as {{ post.firstoption }}.

Comment: I' ve made some typing errors becouse i didnt copy-paste my code but actuali write it on stackowerflow. Otherwise i dont have any errors and problems with sytax. Like i said, i can print values if they arent rendered in other template.I posted an model but i think, model is ok. Otherwise i wouldnt been able to print values in option 1.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably because you need to call `all` on your posts

```
{% for post in instance.posts.all %}
  {{ post.firstoption }}
{% endfor }
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this before and didnt work. 
I also tried {% for post in instance.posts_set.all %}

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi well spoted. it should be `{{`

Comment: typo error. Actualy i got {{. I edited the post.thanks for helping me